# Prod and Floating Point

Tags: r

I'm reproducing a calculation from a paper part of which is...

```
prod(c(0.44, 0.26, 0.21, 0.35, 0.37, 0.42, 0.35, 0.45, 0.34, 0.39, 
0.33, 0.38, 0.26, 0.42, 0.22, 0.22, 0.47))
```

which gives,

```
8.500645e-09
```

However, the paper reports this value as,

```
8.13e-09
```

There are other examples of discrepancies throughout the calculation such as this (another prod() calculation, a lm() that requires both the slope and intercept for subsequent use, the results of which give slightly dissimilar results).

I suspect that I'm looking at a floating point discrepancy but how can I be sure?  If it is a floating point discrepancy what further information would I need to reproduce the calculation with greater precision?

ps  I've read the posts on stackoverflow about with regard to floating point arithmetic.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer. We don't have the paper, they might not have done what they said they did in the paper, etc.

Comment: So what exactly is your question here? What would an answer to this  look like? I can find no way to get the answer that they paper claims. Perhaps they rounded true values to two digits.

Comment: @joran planning to post the calculation on github, will put a link here.

Comment: @BondedDust here's what is behind this post, http://tinyurl.com/mnfgjta any comments welcome.

Comment: @MrFlick can you take this question off hold considering my comment on Dec 12 at 22:29?

Comment: @user1945827 If you would like a question re-opened, it's best to edit to clear up any concerns raised in comments and then click the link to "reopen." This is not anything one person can do, it must be voted on by the community. Perhaps [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems rather unlikely that a floating point error with only 17 items could propagate to the extent of a 5% difference unless the data was being rounded for display but not rounded in the calculation. If, however,the underlying values could be different than the display by up to 0.005, then I seen no problem in thinking this could be "floating point issue" or more accurately a propagation of errors induced by a rounding operation.

```
var <- c(0.44, 0.26, 0.21, 0.35, 0.37, 0.42, 0.35, 0.45, 0.34, 0.39, 
          0.33, 0.38, 0.26, 0.42, 0.22, 0.22, 0.47) 

> prod(var+runif(17, -0.005, 0.005) )
[1] 8.483948e-09
> prod(var+runif(17, -0.005, 0.005) )
[1] 8.778634e-09
> prod(var+runif(17, -0.005, 0.005) )
[1] 8.351511e-09
> prod(var+runif(17, -0.005, 0.005) )
[1] 8.113381e-09
> prod(var+runif(17, -0.005, 0.005) )
[1] 8.224519e-09
> prod(var+runif(17, -0.005, 0.005) )
[1] 8.664986e-09


set.seed(101)
rr <- replicate(1000,prod(var+runif(17, -0.005, 0.005)))
par(las=1,bty="l")
hist(rr,breaks=50,col="gray")
abline(v=c(8.5e-9,8.13e-9),col=c(2,4),lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: @BenBolker: Nice addition. Wish I had a mechanism for points transfer for helpful edits.

Comment: @BenBolker: not only nice but really useful, thanks.